# WPF - change image hue without shaders

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, hue

I have an image in a WPF application that I would like to use as a button, and when the mouse goes over it, clicks it etc I would like the hue to change.

Is it possible to do this without the hassle of using my own custom shaders?

I downloaded AForge.NET's image processing library, but that doesn't really like the WPF Image Control..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the opacity, may be 0.8 when you hover and 0.5 when the mouse is pressed.

Comment: I was hoping to change the hue as I want the button to do a different thing depending on whether it is right clicked or left clicked.. So I want it to go a different color on each of those events.

Comment: It's okay. I ended up editing the image in GIMP and using 4 different images.